# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: is occured

Tags: java, appium

```
public void GameSeeTab() throws InterruptedException {
   Thread.sleep(6000);

   if(driver.findElement(By.xpath(Constant.GAMESEE_TAB)).isDisplayed()) {
      System.out.println("Displayed");
      Thread.sleep(2000);
      AndroidElement hh=driver.findElement(By.xpath(Constant.GAMESEE_TAB));
      hh.click();   // here Webdriver exception is occured  
   }
```

Actually, the element is focused but not clicked.

Answer (score 0):

By your code it seems that the xpath strategy that you're using is incorrect .

ideally your xpath should be like : //className[@attributeName='attributValue']

e.g : //android.view.View[@text='myApp']